# Why does a shared samba directory show different file permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, smb, selinux

The file permission in my samba server (local filesystem) are as follows:

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 sambaserver sambaserver 49 Jan  9 01:14 staticfile.md
```

However, when accessed remotely through a client, the permissions changes to this:

```
-rwx------. 1 sambaclient sambaclient 49 Jan  9 01:14 staticfile.md
```

Why is that so? And why does the file now have execute bit enabled?

Comment: Are you reading the permissions while logged in as the same user in both cases?

Comment: No, they are different users

Comment: I believe samba automatically sets execute on for compability with other OSes, but I also don't think the execute bit actually controls execution, since over samba, the executable is not being executed by the server, but instead on the client.